# Categorize data using sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-aggregation

I have data in the below format in status table (newstat) with unique identifer id

```
  

 id status status1
----- 
 1 COMP ACC REQ 
 2 COMP DECL 
 3 ACR  ACC REQ 
 4 ACR  CANCEL 
 5 ACW     DECL  
 6 ACW     ACC REQ
```

.....

using sql query (oracle 11g) i need the data to be in nested format

```
  
 COMP    ACC REQ, DECL
 ACR     ACC REQ, CANCEL
 ACW     ACC REQ, DECL
```

i have tried code using LISTAGG(), wm_concat

tried using sql but all are generating errors.

ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier

Comment: What is your exact oracle version? `select banner from v$version
where banner like 'Oracle%';` will tell you. `listagg()` was introduced in 11.2 - maybe you are using 11.1 - with 11.2 this definitely works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=00ad48594128add540debc72403f9ced

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
select status, listagg(status1, ', ') within group (order by id) as statuses
from t
group by status
order by min(id);
```

Comment: i tried a similar one including this. when i run this query i am getting below error - ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Comment: @738560 . . .  That is a different error.  You cannot do exactly what you want because the data does not fit into the column that you want.  You could use a CLOB or find some method to shorten the result string.